# Oracle (RAC) vs NoSQL

Tags: oracle, mongodb, cassandra, voldemort, nosql

I am curious if anybody did benchmarks for accessing of data in NoSQL databases vs Oracle (particularly I am talking about Oracle RAC)?
The project requires to work with at least 10mil+ of records, search among them (but not necessary have to be real time), the *read* is very important for speed, and it's also very important to guarantee HA and reliability (can't lose records!!!)
I can see for myself how say Cassandra/MongoDB might be better fit (because key value storage will provide faster reads than SQL when you go over 10mil records), but I find difficult to articulate all of them nicely. Any links? Suggestions? Bullet points?
Thanks!

Comment: My 3 year old laptop handles 10 million rows just fine with a standard installation of Oracle XE.

Comment: In 2012, 10m records is not a large amount of data.  As answered below, 2.5GB will reside in memory very easily on any contemporary system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10 million records. Assume 250 bytes per record. That is about 2.5 Gb of data, which is well within the capacity of a basic desktop / laptop PC. The data volumes are insignificant (unless each record is sized in Mb, such as picture or audio).

What you do need to talk about is transaction volumes (separated into read and write) and what you consider HA. Read-only HA is easy relative to "Read-write HA". It can be trivial to replicate a read-only data set off to multiple servers at different geographic locations and distribute a query workload on them.

It's much harder to scale out an update heavy workload, which is why you often hear about systems going into meltdown when tickets for a big concert are released. Quite simply there's a fixed number of seats and you can't have ten duplicated systems each selling what they *think* is available. There has to be a single source of truth, which means a bottleneck (and potentially a single point of failure).

On the HA aspect, RAC is a shared storage technology which generally means your RAC nodes are in close proximity. That can make them vulnerable to localized events such as a building fire or telecoms breakdown. Data Guard is the Oracle technology that relates to off-site replication and failover.

Comment: 10 milion records, but they expected to grow 30-50% every two week. I wonder at what moment Oracle will be getting slower? I am trying to find any benchmarks if we are going to use Oracle RAC as key-value storage comparing to Cassandra/MongoDB/etc. Who provides better perfomance? I am more interested in reads;

Comment: I am also interested in any Whitepapers on this. Although my requirements are an order of magnitude greater. The problem with getting businesses away from Oracle lies within the name branding of "Oracle." Any real world examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly when you come to comparison of NoSQL vs SQL, you have to understand a very important difference between them. Data in **NoSQL may be inconsistent in cost order to achieve HA**.

What do I mean by inconsistent? It depends, but usually around *3-5 seconds to propagate* the data around nodes. NoSQL database provide mechanism to manage and eliminate that, but if you want all your data be consistent in real time, then you simply use classic SQL, like Oracle RAC.

Coming back to speed comparison: it's simply incomparable which one is faster, because it relays on factors like network infrastructure, computing power and database model etc. But important thing is that at some point you may reach the moment that SQL is **economically inefficient to maintain** and you have to switch to NoSQL.